# Change Text size to avoid scroll when container size changes

Tags: javascript, css, text, sass, contenteditable

Is there any library or best approach to make text inside container visible by changing the text size of the text when container width or height changes.

Comment: Isn't that how it works by default? What kind of container?

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries, it's a simple process that allows you to modify properties according to the size of the container.

[I advice you to look at this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

In those examples, media queries are used for the entire screen, but with the good manipulation, you should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the font size automatically adjust based on the viewport width or viewport height by using `vw` or `vh` instead of whatever you are currently using such as `px`

For example:

```
h3 {
    font-size: 6vw;
}
```

When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, the text will scale.

You can find more detailed information here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths and https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 0):

You already got two CSS methods, I am suggesting you the third one with JavaScript.

You could get advantage over `mousedown` and `mouseup` events since there isn't any method like `resize`.

Look at the example:

```js
const c = document.querySelector("#container");
let screenX, screenY;

c.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  const {offsetWidth, offsetHeight} = e.target;
  screenX = offsetWidth
  screenY = offsetHeight;
});

c.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
  const {offsetWidth, offsetHeight} = e.target;
  if(offsetWidth != screenX || offsetHeight != screenY){
    console.log('resized');
    adaptText(e.target);
  }
});

function adaptText(t){
// do your own trick
  const width = t.offsetWidth,
        height = t.offsetHeight;
  let ems = width/height;
  t.style.fontSize = `${ems}em`;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="container">test</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use [viewport relative units](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/) to always keep your font in sync with window size.

```css
.auto-text { font-size: 5vw; }
```

They are really powerful especially when used with css `calc()` function but ... this'll be useless for content that changes.

2) You can also listen on component's size changes using [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver).

[Example](https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/resize-observer/resize-observer-text.html), [code](https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/master/resize-observer/resize-observer-text.html)

3) there are JS libraries that are resizing text to fit whole container eg: [FitText](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js)

Comment: Thanks for the rezise observer advice. Isaw the intersection observer but never saw the rezise one